# adding images in my project

Tags: c#, image

I'm trying to add/change images in my project, using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 C#. Along with it, Devexpress components are also included.

What I did, I copied an image (.png file) and paste it it in my   "PrintRibbonControllerResources.resx" and then after that I have to open again the MainForm.cs right click on the form and click on the Run Designer. It will open the Ribbon Control Designer. From there, I can add the image.

Do you think its ok? It's my first time to do this, and I don't have any experience & I'm learning it by doing.

Thanks

=== 
it seems I don't see the add function under resource tab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I generally add an image to the project itself. (Add/Existing item) I do this so I can use SourceControl to check in/out the image file. The resx then links to these files.

Basically, my philosophy is: if it works, don't fix it.
If this solution works for you, it's fine. At least, until you discover a situation where it fails.

Answer (score 1):

If you go in the properties of your project, and select the resources tab, you can add it directly from there and it will be accessible in the default resource file of your project, which might be more convenient.

Comment: you mean the whole form of the project?

Comment: I clicked on it but I don't see any add function, where I can add the images

Answer (score 1):

I like to add it to a solution folder (or folder in the project) and like that to the resx via "Add Exising File".

I get all of the advantages of having the resource file, but also the advantages of having a physical file (editing, quick view, etc.)